# Linq sql query Not implementing

Tags: sql, linq

```
 int no = 10;
            var duplicate = from m in context.PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers
                            group m by new {m.CompanyID} into grp
                            where grp.Count()>no
                            select new {grp}
```

I need to get all the comapnyids(one or more) present in the table whose count matches the count i give dyanmically through no .I am unable to complete this any help

Answer (score 1):

The companyId is the key of your grouping, so

```
var duplicate = from m in context.PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers
                            group m by m.CompanyID into grp
                            where grp.Count()>no
                            select  grp.Key;
```

By the way, you don't need to use

```
group m by new {<your property>}
```

if you group by one property only.

Comment: Company id is not the primary key..Can I get Multiple ids of comapny using the above query

Comment: @ManojChowdary who's talking of primary key ? I'm talking about "Grouping key". Yes, you will have all distinct CompanyID.

Comment: @ManojChowdary look at sql generated and try it in your base, then, and see if you're querying the right things...